# Links and text don't work good with hidden and visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/uj3uw9cp/1/

```css
    body {
      color: white;
    }

    a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #text-on-image {
      overflow: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 5%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      margin-top: -10px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    img:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    img:hover + #text-on-image {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_lItiyoxw4jXqQs4Y3rFq7jklnJEJmR-gAeue-Z8gDu8rbh3pRA" width="150" height="150">
<div id="text-on-image">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <p><strong>TEXT</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example on JSFIDDLE, when someone hovers on the image, it will display a link and some text. My main problem is if someone hover on the text or links, the opacity deleted.

So I want that if someone hovers on the link or the text, the opacity will still be 0.8. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in a div and change css to hover over div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing opacity

That happens because when you hover the text, that will be the hovered element and the image will lost the hover. To solve this, just place the whole block into a container and place the hover selector to that element and select the contained image within it:

```css
#container:hover > img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

### [Updated solution/JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8j8vkppe/)

```css
body {
    color: white;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#text-on-image {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-top: -10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#container:hover > img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#container:hover > img + #text-on-image {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_lItiyoxw4jXqQs4Y3rFq7jklnJEJmR-gAeue-Z8gDu8rbh3pRA" width="150" height="150">
    <div id="text-on-image">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <p><strong>TEXT</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Other recommendations

Keep in mind that in HTML5 elements have semantic meaning. Don't use them for their default styling. Achieve the needed style with CSS.

#### The `<strong>` element

> The `<strong>` element represents a span of text with strong importance.
>
> [From W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/strong.html)

For its style, use: `font-weight: bold;`

#### The `<i>` element

In some libraries `<i>` is used for icons, but that is against the HTML specification. Use `<span>` for this purpose.

> The `<i>` element represents a span of text offset from its surrounding content without conveying any extra emphasis or importance, and for which the conventional typographic presentation is italic text; for example, a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, a thought, or a ship name.
>
> [From W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/i.html)

For its style, use: `font-style: italic;`

Answer (score 1):

As you also mentioned `Javascript/Jquery`, I pose another solution using it

```js
$('img,#text-on-image').mouseenter(function(){
 $('img').css('opacity', '0.8')
})
$('img').mouseleave(function(){
 $('img').css('opacity', '1')
})
```

```css
body {
  color:white;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#text-on-image {
  overflow: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 5%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        margin-top: -10px;
        visibility: hidden;
        
}

#container:hover>img + #text-on-image {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">


<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_lItiyoxw4jXqQs4Y3rFq7jklnJEJmR-gAeue-Z8gDu8rbh3pRA" width="150" height="150">
  <div id="text-on-image">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <p><strong>TEXT</strong></p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `visibility` also in `#text-on-image:hover`, check below code

```
img:hover + #text-on-image,
#text-on-image:hover {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Or wrap whole item in to another div and change css to hover over div, check below code

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_lItiyoxw4jXqQs4Y3rFq7jklnJEJmR-gAeue-Z8gDu8rbh3pRA" width="150" height="150">
  <div id="text-on-image">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <p><strong>TEXT</strong></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#text-on-image {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: -10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.parent:hover #text-on-image {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Case One: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/uj3uw9cp/8/

Case two: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/uj3uw9cp/7/

Comment: Hope this is the relevant answer , if it is then add acceptable flag ;)